# Javascript images invisible, but only in Google Chrome on Fedora

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, fedora

I'm working on a web app that allows users to send messages over a websocket to tell the webpage to show images or to clear all images off the screen.

However, sometimes, an image seems to be invisible. When I click the area where the image should be, Javascript registers the image as being clicked. If I open up the Chrome developer tools, the image becomes visible. (I don't need to inspect the element; just hitting F12 will do.)

I only see this bug appear in Google Chrome on Fedora (which, unfortunately, all the computers using our web app will be). When I tested it in Google Chrome on Windows, I didn't see it.

The closest StackOverflow issue I've run into appears to be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19956546/images-not-showing-in-chrome-until-i-click-inspect-element). However, this issue didn't seem to get an agreed-upon answer. I wanted to try its Z-Axis suggestion, but in order to position the image at specific user-requested coordinates, I (think) I have to use position:fixed, which doesn't seem to allow for Z-Axis coordinates. Going along with the other suggestions in the answer for this issue, the parent container doesn't appear to be in a strange place, and I can't disable Javascript because I need it for the web app to work properly. I didn't need to hover over the invisible image with the developer tools in order to make it appear, so I didn't look into hover-related bugfixes.

I created a simplified version of the web app that shows an image by default. When the user clicks the image, it clears the screen, waits a few seconds, and then puts the image back on the screen. [I put this version in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ho7Lyyr2/3/). When I opened the Fiddle in Google Chrome on Fedora, the bug appeared again after clicking the image, having the page clear, and seeing the image reappear several times (probably somewhere between 10 and 50 times).

My simplified page is as follows:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:relative;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    placeImageOnscreen(); 
});

function placeImageOnscreen() {
    console.log("Placing the image on the screen.");
    var imageObject = document.createElement("img");
    imageObject.src = "http://a-z-animals.com/media/animals/images/original/bearded_dragon1.jpg";

    imageObject.addEventListener("click", clearScreen, false);

    var containerDiv = document.getElementById("container");
    containerDiv.appendChild(imageObject);

}

function clearScreen() {
    console.log("Clearing the image off the screen.");
    $('#container img').remove();

    setTimeout(placeImageOnscreen, 3000);
}
```

Is this a bug in Fedora's version of Google Chrome? Does anyone have any insight as to why images are sometimes present but not visible?

Comment: What are `#container` width and height `100%` compared to? Give a height and width to the parent Element, in this case the `body`, because `%` is based on parent.

Comment: I think `#container` is a child of `body`. I'm hoping to make `#container` the same width and height as the browser window. Is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: `$(window).height()` and `$(window).width()` in jQuery.

Comment: Thank you! I realized that I'd need to resize the container when the user resizes the window, so I tried `height:100vh; width:100vw`. Unfortunately, when I tried that, the invisible image bug didn't go away. Is there a way to use your JQuery solution to resize when the window resizes? Is there a better way to do this?